# What is the difference between POSTGRES _text and text[][] array types?

Tags: postgresql, array

I'm using a postgres database created by a script ([Osm2pgsql](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osm2pgsql)). It has created some fields with the type `_text` for two dimensional arrays of `text`. I'm trying to understand why it didn't just create a `text[][]` field, and why this type exists in postgres.

I can find [this link](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/xtypes.html) in the docs which says:

> When you define a new base type, PostgreSQL automatically provides support for arrays of that type. The array type typically has the same name as the base type with the underscore character (_) prepended.

But I don't understand why it is using this "underscored" type name when text is a built in type of postgres?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`_text` and `text[]` are interchangeable in PostgreSQL. Also `text[][]` is the same data type.

To make things clearer: `type[]` means "the array type whose elements are of type `type`", and the actual name of that type is `_type`. The reason for that choice of name is that when a type is created, an associated array type is created as well. The name of that internal array type is determined by calling the C function `makeArrayTypeName` with the type name as argument. This in turn calls `makeUniqueTypeName`, whose code comment describes what it does:

```
/*
 * makeUniqueTypeName
 *      Generate a unique name for a prospective new type
 *
 * Given a typeName, return a new palloc'ed name by prepending underscores
 * until a non-conflicting name results.
 *
 * If tryOriginal, first try with zero underscores.
 */
```

In principle, there would be no problem in renaming `_type` to something else, but PostgreSQL forbids that in order to avoid confusion.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I find it confusing that they have two notations for arrays. I'm guessing this is for historical reasons?

Comment: No, I'd say for technical reasons. Each type must have a name, and choosing `type[]` as the name would require double quotes around it and may lead to interesting confusion between `type[]` and `"type[]"`.