# How to differentiate text[] and text[][] when both have the same internal type _text?

Tags: postgresql

According to https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/307373/156984, both `text[]` and `text[][]` have the same internal type `_text`.
If the internal type of both is the same, how can I then actually differentiate them?

`SELECT * FROM pg_type;` just returns one row, representing both types. I would expect it to return two, one for `text[]` and one for `text[][]`.

EDIT:
The reason I need this information is that i kind of want to reverse engineer `text[]` or `text[][]` from `_text` to then send the type information as a String to a client.

Comment: array_dims ( anyarray ) → text

Comment: For this to work I need to have an instance of a specific array, however I don't have this at the time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to Postgres array documentation, Postgres does not differentiate between one- and multidimensional arrays in its type.

> The current implementation does not enforce the declared number of
> dimensions either. Arrays of a particular element type are all
> considered to be of the same type, regardless of size or number of
> dimensions. So, declaring the array size or number of dimensions in
> CREATE TABLE is simply documentation; it does not affect run-time
> behavior.

For example, both `int[]` and `int[][]` have the same type `_int`.

It is possible to get the dimensions of an array from `pg_attribute.attndims`.

Sources:

- https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/arrays.html
- https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/252#issuecomment-1240674582